# Dart Regex: Only allow dot and numbers

Tags: regex, dart

I need to format the price string in dart.

String can be: `₹&nbsp;2,19,990.00`
String can be: `$1,114.99`
String can be: `$14.99`

What I tried:

```
void main() {
  String str = "₹&nbsp;2,19,990.00";
  RegExp regexp = RegExp("(\\d+[,.]?[\\d]*)");
  RegExpMatch? match = regexp.firstMatch(str);
  str = match!.group(1)!;
  print(str);
}
```

What my output is: `2,19`
What my output is: `1,114`
What my output is: `14.99`

Expected output: `219990.00`
Expected output: `1114.99`
Expected output: `14.99` (This one is correct because there is no comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for search:

```sh
^\D+|(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

And replace with an empty string i.e. `""`.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\D+`: Match 1+ non-digit characters
- `|`: OR
- `(?<=\d),(?=\d)`: Match a comma if it surrounded with digits on both sides
  [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PXdera/1)

**Code:** Using `replaceAll` method:

```sh
str = str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^\D+|(?<=\d),(?=\d)'), '');
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to replace all non-digit/non-dot characters with nothing.

The most efficient way to do that is:

```dart
final re = RegExp(r"[^\d.]+");
String sanitizeCurrency(String input) => input.replaceAll(re, "");
```

You can't do it by *matching* because a match is always contiguous in the source string, and you want to omit the embedded `,`s.